# Modify drop of shulker box

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a server with friends on vanilla 1.13.2 and I am trying to change the drop of the shulker box. I want that always drop 2 shulker shells but I can't make that they drop correctly.

I tried puting a shulker.JSON in data/loot_tables/minecraft/entities but nothing happend.

the content of the .JSON was:

```
{
"pools": [
    {
        "rolls": 1,
        "entries": [
            {
                "type": "item",
                "name": "minecraft:shulker_shell",
                "weight": 1,
                "functions": [
                    {
                        "function": "set_count",
                        "count": 2
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Do you have `pack.mcmeta`?

Comment: Also, isn't it `minecraft/loot_tables/entities`?

Comment: Can't you just put a shulker shell in the shulker box, so that it always drops 2.

Comment: @FabianRöling I think that `pack.mcmeta` is for datapacks and I'm in the data folder. I will try with that other directory.

Comment: [Resource pack that does just that](https://xisumavoid.com/downloads2/datapack/double%20shulker%20shells%20v1.0.0.zip).

Comment: @SF. Datapack not resource pack fyi.

Answer (score 1):

Your loot file needs to be at `somedatapack/data/minecraft/loot_tables/entities/shulker.json`, not `somedatapack/data/loot_tables/minecraft/entities`. Here's the double shulker shell loot file I use:

```
{
  "pools": [
    {
      "rolls": 2,
      "entries": [
        {
          "type": "minecraft:item",
          "name": "minecraft:shulker_shell"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If it still doesn't work, try renaming it to `shulker.json` instead of `shulker.JSON`. I'm not sure if it's case-sensitive.